# jQuery UI Masked Picker : Cant Remove keyboard block input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I used this library for my custom picker[jQuery UI Masked Picker](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/jquery-ui-masked-picker/), everything work well after I need remove feature disable keyboard input, this is the feature I used, I just want after select I need the value still editable.

```
$('.maskedpicker').maskedpicker({
  maxWidth: 500,
  mask: [
    {
      'type': 'select', 
      'page': 'Result Scan', 
      'values': [['hell','hello']],
    },
  ],
  maxWidth: 1366,
  onKeypress: function(handled, e, options, currmask, bodyDiv, pos, mask){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(handled);
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.key);
  }
});
```

I try to read documentation but I cant find anything for my case, if you know how to solve my case with this library I really appreciate or know another library with custom value like this

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on the docs:

> **onKeypress: null**
>
> An optional callback function that will be called whenever the user presses a key. Useful for handling custom selection and navigation. Note that this may require using "private" widget calls (underscore prefix) to get full functionality working.
>
> Default: null
>
> Params: onKeypress(handled, e, options, currmask, bodyDiv, pos, mask)
>
> Return: handled (modified as necessary)

I would advise:

```
onKeypress: function(handled, e, options, currmask, bodyDiv, pos, mask){
  console.log(e);
  console.log(handled);
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.key);
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

This will do two things. Consider the `preventDefault()`:

> The `event.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an element from happening

This will stop the keypress event. We can then stop the callback function:

> When JavaScript reaches a return statement, the function will stop executing.
>
> If the function was invoked from a statement, JavaScript will "return" to execute the code after the invoking statement.
>
> Functions often compute a return value. The return value is "returned" back to the "caller".

This will send a `false` value back to the `onKeyPress` callback indicating the function is complete.

Comment: i like that idea, although that method is fail, i solve it but i need go dive to library and delete that little thing.if u know library similar with this masked picker please share it, thank's for try to help.